# How can I convert PCWSTR to a char[] or wchar_t[]

Tags: c++, windows, string, unicode

I'm trying to create a file, where one of the parameters has been passed in to the method and is of the type PCWSTR. My code creates a .url file and saves the Url into the file:

```
        wchar_t array1[] = "[InternetShortcut]\nURL=";
        wchar_t array2[] = pdwFavoriteUrl;
        wchar_t * DataBuffer = new wchar_t[wcslen(array1) + std::strlen(array2) + 1];
        std::strcpy(DataBuffer,array1);
        std::strcat(DataBuffer,array2);

        // Write data to file
        DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);
        DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
        BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;

        bErrorFlag = WriteFile(hFile, DataBuffer, dwBytesToWrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

        if (FALSE == bErrorFlag)
        {
            // Log error
            hr = E_FAIL;
        }
        else
        {
            if (dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite)
            {
                // Log error
                hr = E_FAIL;
            }
            else
            {
                // Log success
                hr = S_OK;
                //_tprintf(TEXT("Wrote %d bytes to %s successfully.\n"), dwBytesWritten, argv[1]);
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(hFile);
```

I am aware that the code will not compile as-is, since there are conflicting versions of unicode and non-unicode string methods. The line of interest is this one:

```
wchar_t array2[] = pdwFavoriteUrl;
```

pdwFavoriteUrl is of type PCWSTR and there is no way around it. Please help convert it to wchar_t[] (preferred) or char[].

Comment: I'd just create a `std::wstring` out of it and use the buffer (C++11).

Comment: An array cannot be initialized with a pointer. It doesn't appear that you need `array2` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `PCWSTR` is just an alias for `wchar_t*` and in case it is null-terminated that the simplest thing to do would be using it to construct an object of type `std::wstring`. Just pass it to constructor:

```
PCWSTR wcstr = L"My String";
std::wstring wstr(wcstr);
```

and work with `std::wstring` objects instead of doing evil stuff such as:

```
wchar_t * DataBuffer = new wchar_t[wcslen(array1) + std::strlen(array2) + 1];
```

which will probably bring you nothing but unpleasant problems and memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
wchar_t array2[] = pdwFavoriteUrl;
```

and change the call to `strcat` to

```
std::strcat(DataBuffer, pwdFavoriteUrl);
```

(and similarly, replace `array2` with `pwdFavoriteUrl` in the call to `strlen`.)

Note that `PCWSTR` is just

```
typedef const wchar_t * PCWSTR;
```